# We need help with Reddcoin C++ - 1 btc bounty for solution

Tags: litecoin, c++

We need some help with Reddcoin. We had a bug in our code, 2 lines were commented so the verification of block we’re not done properly.

https://github.com/reddcoin/reddcoin/commit/88fc5fe0bf522e384b7aebfebced12b75e207e80

Someone exploited that error and he was able to grab 7k block in 1 hours. We were able to delete those block but we still need to use the block before 44877, and fix the bug for future block.

What we need to do is this. We need to get nHeight in this function so we can ask the code to check only after block 44877.

in main.cpp, function

bool CBlock::CheckBlock(CValidationState &state, bool fCheckPOW, bool fCheckMerkleRoot) const

I need to get access to the nHeight of the block and that’s it to fix the problem.

You can look at our source code to make some test at

https://github.com/reddcoin/reddcoin

1 BTC bounty for anyone who can fix this.

Thanks

Reddcoin

Comment: This is not a question and has no answer, therefore it is not a good fit for a Q&A style site. Other than that, there are too many glaring issues to deal with than I would care to mention. Good luck I guess.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an attempt to solicit a programmer for hire.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is find a freelance site like Odesk, Guru, Freelancer, or Rentacoder, and find someone who has the requisite qualifications. Offer to pay them fair market value for their time, and fix the problem.

You're probably looking at $30 to $40 an hour for someone who can fix this.

While you're there, you should also have them do a full security audit of your codebase. If I had to wager a guess, the whole project should run you about $3,000 or about 4.66 BTC.

Good luck. I like what Reddcoin is about. Would love to see it succeed. If you need any help picking out or managing your developers on this, let me know. I have some experience in sourcing.